# fineuploader how to override the provided UUID

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

We're trying to pass an unique ID into Fineuploader (4.2.2, JQUERY) and reuse that into the fineuploader.js to set the foldername of where the upload is stored.

We basicly found two option:

1. Set the request option uuidName, which should be a string. Passing this one will result in "null" in console and doesn't do the trick.
2. Create a params request option where we define a variable with a value.

Option 2 get passed though we've got no idea how we get this value and process it into fineuploader.js (and alter the qq.getUniqueId-function with this new var for example).

Anyone know how we can get this done?

Thanks so much!

EDIT:
Underneath the code which initiates the uploader, how do I get the fileID inside the fineuploader.js?

```
$(".fine-uploader").fineUploader({
            request: {
                endpoint: 'server/endpoint',
                params: {
                    fileID: '12345'
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to override the UUID Fine Uploader creates for a file, you can do so either by passing your new UUID client-side via the [`setUuid` method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setUuid), or your server can return a `newUuid` property with its value set to the new UUID in its JSON response.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you explain how to use such a method, the documentation doesn't describe how to use is.

Comment: `uploader.setUuid(fileId, newUuid);`

Comment: I've tried this within the fineuploader.js and it works perfectly, from the initial call I use:

Comment: a parameter to pass through an ID, I've updated the initial question with this value. How do I retreive this parameter inside fineuploader.js?

Comment: You must pass in the file ID that Fine Uploader assigns to the file.